# ckeditor shows html content as plain text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I am using CK editor to save HTML data into database, Its saving into database, but while viewing the HTML data, it shows as plain text.

For example

```
&lt;div class=&quot;testimg&quot;&gt; Legion of Honor Museum Chill LoremLegion of Honor Museum Chill LoremLegion of Honor Museum Chill LoremLegion of Honor Museum Chill LoremLegion of Honor Museum Chill &lt;/div&gt;
```

Please help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: Means You are echo That And it shows like this  ?

Comment: Or use mysqli_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use htmlspecialchars_decode() function to display the content with html tags

```
$str = "&lt;div class=&quot;testimg&quot;&gt; Legion of Honor Museum Chill LoremLegion of Honor Museum Chill LoremLegion of Honor Museum Chill LoremLegion of Honor Museum Chill LoremLegion of Honor Museum Chill &lt;/div&gt;
";
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should place the following code in the html tag:

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{ __html: yourContent }}
```

For example:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{ __html: yourContent }}></div>
```

For more detail, the following video tutorial can help you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnHwh-71bPM